# Sikuli saving screen capture issue

Tags: automation, sikuli

I'm trying to write a script that has Sikuli saving a screenshot when something changes. I would like it to prompt me to capture a screenshot but I'm unsure of what command to use - `wait()` vs `waitVanish()`. I can't make sense of the documentation.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import shutil
import os
screenshotsDir = "C:\Users\home\Dropbox\TEMP"
img = capture()
waitVanish(img,FOREVER)
shutil.move(img,os.path.join(screenshotsDir,xx.png))
```

Is `waitVanish()` the right command?

Comment: Do you really want **you** to be prompted to make a screenshot manually or you want that to happen automatically? Are you experiencing any issues with the above code? Does it work properly for you?

Comment: @eugenes30 I want to be prompted... Unless there is a different way.           Basically, I want Sikuli to watch a list and when the list changes, take a screenshot and store (which works above) and watch that list again, using the screenshot as the next basis for comparison...

Comment: So what is the problem you are currently having?

Comment: The waitVanish function doesn't seem to work. I captured a part of the screen (e.g. a radio button with some text next to it) and when I changed that section, it didn't work).

Comment: I can't test it at the moment so I am not sure what type the `capture()` function returns. `waitVanish()` function should get 2 parameters where the first one is a Region.

Comment: The capture function requests user to select a region on the screen. I ported the code to my mac and it seems to work.. intermittently. Does waitvanish exclude the cursor when monitoring?

Comment: I apparently don't have enough points to chat.. I somehow got it to work... Do you know how to restart the script by renewing the initial screenshot (img, above) at the same window dimensions & position in screen?